# No row in catalog_eav_attribute for my 'created_at' attribute ID

Tags: mysql, magento, sorting, categories

I have a magento v1.7.0.2 store and an trying to add sort by 'Newest' to our category pages.

I've read several guides which suggest finding the attribute ID for 'created_at' in our eav_attribute table (in our case it's ID = 17) then finding the corresponding row in the catalog_eav_attribute table and setting the `used_for_sort_by` = 1

This all sounds easy enough, but I don't have any row in catalog_eav_attribute for any attribute with an ID less than 33. I checked another magento store and that was also id= 17 for created_at, but had no entries in catalog_eav_attribute for any attribute less than 41.

Can anyone explain this or help me to (re)create the entry I need for this to work?
thanks,
James

[image: attribute_id = 17]

[image: nothing less than id = 41]

Answer (score 1):

Sorted!
Here's the answer I needed:

**Attributes in Magento belong to Entity types (sales, customer, product, category, etc...). You have two attributes called "created_at", one is for the customers (entity type 1, entity id 17) and the other one was for products (entity type 4, entity id 102). This is the latter you should have been looking at.**

Once I had that info, I was back on track and have sorted the job.

Comment: Thanks helped me figure out my own issue with the same. Just to say the ID will be different dependent on how many attributes you've added.